# How to include a colon in a Visual Studio extension DisplayName

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'd like to use a colon (`:`) as part of my extension's `DisplayName`. I've modified my .vsixmanifest file as such:

```
 <DisplayName>Foo:Bar &amp; Baz</DisplayName>
```

But, at build time I get an error:

```
Error trying to read the VSIX manifest file "obj\x86\Debug\extension.vsixmanifest". 
The given path's format is not supported.
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-extension-schema-2-0-reference?view=vs-2019) say nothing about any character limitation, only that `DisplayName` must be less than 50 characters.

I've even tried encoding the colon, but I get the same error message (above).

```
 <DisplayName>Foo&#58;Bar &amp; Baz</DisplayName>
```

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to include a colon in a Visual Studio extension DisplayName

I am afraid that you cannot get what you want.

**Colon** is an illegal character in the **vsixmanifest** file and therefore cannot be used in it.

**Suggestion**

We suggest you could use `_` rather than `:`.

**In addition**, if you still want this feature, you could suggest this feature on [our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Hmmm, I guess in that case, I'll use a `-`, thanks!